# jq with pipe error. Without pipe not error

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to call an api and in the same line parse its output with `jq`.
If I do all in one line it gives me an error:

```
bash-4.2$ call_api -s "job=work_1*&status=Executing"  | $PATH_API/jq '.statuses[].name // empty' --raw-output
parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2301, column 61
```

But if I redirect the api's output to a file and then apply `jq` to that file it doesn't raise any error:

```
bash-4.2$ call_api -s "job=work_1*&status=Executing"  > /tmp/kk
bash-4.2$  $PATH_API/jq '.statuses[].name // empty' --raw-output /tmp/kk
work_1_002103ALLGDC
work_1_000049EVEFIN
work_1_002038ALF003
```

Do you know why? Is it possible to fix it to can achieve it in one line?

Comment: Try `call_api -s "job=work_1*&status=Executing" | tee /tmp/kk >/dev/null` (after having deleted /tmp/kk if it still exists), see if `$PATH_API/jq '.statuses[].name // empty' --raw-output /tmp/kk` also fails, if so check the content of `/tmp/kk` and try to see what's wrong. Some programs behave differently when their output is piped, that might be your problem

Comment: Also note that "doing things in one line" rarely is a productive goal and often a counter-productive one, but that if it really matters to you, you always have the option of separating commands by `;` rather than by linefeeds

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with call_api itself - since it's not defined what that is. Some programs (e.g. curl, more) behave slightly differently depending on where their output goes. Typically the big distinction is between tty and not-a-tty but you may find differences between pipe and regular file. There should be no inherent difference in jq's behavior.

```
richard@sophia:~/cc/dpbuilder (bug/T-10571) $ jq -r '.[]' < fred.json 
Hello
World
richard@sophia:~/cc/dpbuilder (bug/T-10571) $ jq -r '.[]' fred.json 
Hello
World
richard@sophia:~/cc/dpbuilder (bug/T-10571) $ cat fred.json | jq -r '.[]'
Hello
World
richard@sophia:~/cc/dpbuilder (bug/T-10571) $
```

Also check how large the output is - you may be running into limits in terms of piped output. In particular, is it greater than 64k?

Comment: Actually, there are differences in jq's behavior depending on the input. If stdin is redirected to a file, the filter for example is not required. See: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1110 It wouldn't surprise me if it behaved (subtly) different if the output is redirected.